# I'm facing this error Cannot use object of type mysqli as array

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Controoler:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\Services;

class Detail extends Controller
{
    public function nadeem($id)
    {
       $model= new Services();
       $data = $model->select('text','title','image')->where('id',$id);
       $nadeem['result'] = $data->get();
       return view('service_detail', $nadeem);              
    }
}
```

view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Service</title>
</head>
<body>



<?php if ($result): ?> 
    <?php foreach ($result as $key => $value): ?> 
         <p><?php echo $value['text'];?></p> 
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm facing this error

> Cannot use object of type mysqli as array

How can solve this problem.

Comment: Please add the code of your model too.

Comment: Which of all these lines causes that error? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the controller to this:

```
$model = new Services();
$nadeem['result'] = $model->select('text, title, image')->where('id',$id)->findAll();
return view('service_detail', $nadeem);
```

Basically in your case you're sending to the view the query object and not the query result.

This answer assumes that you're using the codeigniter 4 Model and not a custom model since you didn't post the model.

Comment: thanks its work but just fetching text I have an image field in database but the image not showing

Comment: when I put image filed first like select('image','text') then the image is show and text does not show

Comment: @NÂdeemMÅlik changed the answer to reflect what you need. Look at the select. If it works don't forget to mark as answered. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, use the select with just one string instead of many. So instead of select('foo', 'bar') use select('foo, bar') like my answer. @NÂdeemMÅlik

Comment: @NÂdeemMÅlik can you please mark the answer as correct?